# ::before rule doesn't follow the size of the element

Tags: html, css

I try to add a border on the bottom of an `h4` title with some extra css and custom length. I know that the only way, compatible with the most browsers is using the `::before` rule. However, I have the following problem on the code:

```
<div class="my_div_class">
        <h4>This is a title</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
</div>


.my_div_class h4::before {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    content: "";
    width: 75%;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    left: 12.5%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.my_div_class h4 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.my_div_class {
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

The border goes to the end of the page (or in my website, to the end of the bigger `div` element) instead of the end of the `h4`.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/550ttypa/). You can barely see it in the bottom of the page.

Comment: Add `position: relative` to the pseudo element's parent (the `h4` element).

Answer (score 0):

```
.my_div_class h4::before {
   position:absolute;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    content: "";
    width: 75%;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    margin-top:1em;
    left: 12.5%;
}
```

What has changed:

- bottom:0; <--- Removed
- margin-top:1em; <--- Added

https://jsfiddle.net/550ttypa/3/